# Module not found: Can't resolve '../styles/global.css' in an next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

[image]I am following the instruction on :
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/global-styles

And getting error message when adding import '../styles/global.css'
to _app.js

./pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../styles/global.css' in 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\tradingCFD\pages'

Comment: did u created css file at C:\Users\Owner\Documents\tradingCFD\styles\global.css

Comment: yes I created a file : global.css

Comment: Please provide the exact code snippets with your relevant directory structure, and _.app.js relevant code

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the folder structure and this is the _app.js code: import '../styles/global.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css

Comment: In my case, the tutorial ask to create `global.css`, but the code example was `globals.css` (globals with an s)

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue. The tutorial tells you to restart the server, do it.

> **Restart the Development Server**

> Important: You need to restart the development server when you add pages/_app.js. Press Ctrl + c to stop
> the server and run:

```
 npm run dev
```

If you put **_app** and **global** in the correct folders, it should run OK.

Comment: As simple as it sounds, this is the solution to image and video issues if you use them in Next.js

Answer (score 4):

Your global.css seems to be in public/styles., not just styles/. The styles directory should be moved up a level to be in the app root.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same problem as the OP but in my case, using `styled-components` `createGlobalStyle`, I incorrectly referenced the file as `../styles/global` and it build fine locally *even though* the filename was `Global.js`. The build on Vercel wasn't so lenient.

TLDR:
double check capitalization on file refs

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
```

with

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

This points to the missed style-loader. Have you npm install --save-dev style-loader?
If not, make sure to install the loader you required first.

Comment: Also try removing the file yourself and type it again, if you used the next.js template in the documentation tutorial

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by running
`npm run tailwind`